# Bad kerning, oh my!

Tags: bug, design

The kerning on the text used on user pages for questions and answers is not great. It's very noticeable with lowercase c's.

[image]

Normally I wouldn't complain about this (it's pretty trivial), but the effect is a bit more... *prominent* with the cl digraph.

Could this be fixed? It shouldn't take more than five minutes.

Comment: What's your browser and operating system? Yes it does matter.

Comment: *Dealing with point and dick harass!* makes for a great title for a guide about MOBA report systems ...

Comment: @3ventic Thanks; I searched for "kerning is:question" but it didn't  come up. Come to think about it, that second term probably isn't even useful.

Comment: @badp I would like for someone to have another look at the issue, since there was no counterpoint in the original question. Is the correct procedure on meta (with its lack of bounties) to simply leave another comment? Or has consensus already been reached and thus I can do nothing about it?

Comment: @schism we can't look at the issue if we don't know what browser and operating system you're using